# Is it possible to change a database by SQL SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-injection

We want to allow to an administrator (only) to execute an SQL SELECT statement via Web UI.
Please note that the administrator is allowed to view all information in a database.

What are security risks with this approach?
Is it possible to change somehow a database by SQL SELECT statement (any record or table)?

*added*

RDBMS is PostgreSQL

Comment: For further read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: I do know what is SQL injection. My question is different: Is it possible to change somehow a database by SQL SELECT statement (any record or table)?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you talking about? If there is a way, it's most likely RDBMS specific.

Comment: Yes, every SQL statement that takes parameters is subject to SQL Injection.

Comment: `SELECT INTO newTable FROM oldTable `... this create tables.

Comment: You can always use the full qualified identifier `database.table`.

Comment: did you mean the `SELECT` privilege? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html -- or you will parse the query (provided on this ui), and only execute `SELECT` ones?

Comment: Execution of the select command.
Unfortunately (thanks to mmhasannn) it is possible to change values using `SELECT INTO newTable FROM oldTable`: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-selectinto.html

Comment: @Michael it depends. if you use the `SELECT` privilege only for that role, I'm (almost) sure it won't allow `SELECT INTO` statements (however the docs doesn't clarify this explicitly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We want to allow to an administrator (only) to execute an SQL SELECT statement via Web UI. Please note that the administrator is allowed to view all information in a database.
>
> What are security risks with this approach? Is it possible to change somehow a database by SQL SELECT statement (any record or table)?

Well, how do you propose to let them execute `SELECT` statements? PostgreSQL doesn't have user-level statement privileges, it has privileges on individual database objects.

In theory you can absolutely modify the database with `SELECT`. Just look at PostgreSQL's function list. Not to mention the user-defined functions. The most obvious case is of course `nextval`, which advances a sequence, or `setval` which sets a sequence's position.

However, everything requires rights on the associated database objects. If you only `GRANT` the `SELECT` right on a table (or some subset of the column's tables) then the user won't be able to modify the data in that table directly. Nor does PostgreSQL provide functions to bypass that restriction built-in. So simply creating a user with only `SELECT` rights to some tables and `USAGE` rights on the schemas they're in should be fine.

There are some important caveats though. *`SECURITY DEFINER` user defined functions can do anything the defining user can do* so if you have `SECURITY DEFINER` user defined functions that weren't carefully written you might have opened security holes. The same is true of user-defined functions written in C - so consider your extensions carefully. Finally, you need to be extremely careful about any functions written in "untrusted" languages like plpython, plperl, etc (as opposed to plperlu which is sandboxed) as these must be implemented carefully to make sure the calling user can't trick them into doing things they weren't supposed to do.

If you plan to give a user direct access to write raw SQL you have to be more careful about securing your DB. Don't `GRANT` rights to `public`, and `REVOKE` them where they're granted by default. Check `security definer` functions to make sure they have a `SET search_path` option defined. Etc. It's generally safe, but only if you're careful.